# All FTP using programs try to login with anonymous at first

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

When using Krusader or Konquerer or such to connect to ftp://myhost.tld it starts trying anonymous access, and then ask me for my password. the problem is, myhost blocks me after 10 failed attempts to login for my ip, so after transferring some files i need to reset the ipfilter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ftp://user:password@myhost.tld as URL..?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall having that *starting anonymously* problem with Konqueror on Kubuntu, but now I'm using gFTP on Ubuntu 9.10, it's definitely **not** a problem.

I also used gFTP on Kubuntu. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/):

> FileZilla Client is a fast and reliable cross-platform FTP, FTPS and
>   SFTP client with lots of useful features and an intuitive graphical
>   user interface. Features
>
> Among others, the features of FileZilla include the following:
>
> ```
> Easy to use
> Supports FTP, FTP over SSL/TLS (FTPS) and SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
> Cross-platform. Runs on Windows, Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X and more
> IPv6 support
> Available in many languages
> Supports resume and transfer of large files >4GB
> Tabbed user interface
> Powerful Site Manager and transfer queue
> Bookmarks
> Drag & drop support
> Configurable transfer speed limits
> Filename filters
> Directory comparison
> Network configuration wizard
> Remote file editing
> Keep-alive
> HTTP/1.1, SOCKS5 and FTP-Proxy support
> Logging to file
> Synchronized directory browsing
> Remote file search
> ```

[image]